# Find logs which not contains specified field in kibana

Tags: search, kibana, elastic-stack

I use ELK to arrange my logs, logs goes from many places and some records might not contain several fields and the question is what is the best way to find such records? Can I find logs which not contains several fields?

Answer (score 0):

Kibana uses the [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) syntax of Elasticsearch in its filters. The syntax to find a document that does not have a given field is `_missing_:FIELD_NAME`. The `+` operator is the preferred way to ensure that a particular search term must be present in the matched documents. Combining these two will allow you to search for documents that are missing multiple fields:

```
+_missing_:foo +_missing_:bar +_missing_:baz
```